# Find NiFi Remote Process Group is Enabled or Disabled via its Rest API

Tags: api, apache-nifi

Using NiFi REST API,

1. How to find a **Remote Process Group** is Enabled or Disabled?
2. Difference between *transmitting* (RemoteProcessGroupDTO) and *transmissionStatus* (RemoteProcessGroupStatusDTO) in NiFi?

Endpoint:
https://nifihost:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/{id}/remote-process-groups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.How to find a Remote Process Group is Enabled or Disabled?

You need to use different end point to find a RPG is enabled or not

```
https://nifihost:8080/nifi-api/remote-process-groups/{id}
```

You may parse the json and check value for *transmitting in component object* OR *transmissionStatus in status object*

2.Difference between transmitting (RemoteProcessGroupDTO) and transmissionStatus (RemoteProcessGroupStatusDTO) in NiFi?

Both of them show the status of RPG transmitting is boolean and transmissionStatus can have string values

```
{
    "revision": {…},
    "id": "value",
    "uri": "value",
    "position": {…},
    "permissions": {…},
    "bulletins": [{…}],
    "disconnectedNodeAcknowledged": true,
    "component": {
        "id": "value",
        "versionedComponentId": "value",
        "parentGroupId": "value",
        "position": {…},
        "targetUri": "value",
        "targetUris": "value",
        "targetSecure": true,
        "name": "value",
        "comments": "value",
        "communicationsTimeout": "value",
        "yieldDuration": "value",
        "transportProtocol": "value",
        "localNetworkInterface": "value",
        "proxyHost": "value",
        "proxyPort": 0,
        "proxyUser": "value",
        "proxyPassword": "value",
        "authorizationIssues": ["value"],
        "validationErrors": ["value"],
        "transmitting": true,
        "inputPortCount": 0,
        "outputPortCount": 0,
        "activeRemoteInputPortCount": 0,
        "inactiveRemoteInputPortCount": 0,
        "activeRemoteOutputPortCount": 0,
        "inactiveRemoteOutputPortCount": 0,
        "flowRefreshed": "value",
        "contents": {…}
    },
    "status": {
        "groupId": "value",
        "id": "value",
        "name": "value",
        "targetUri": "value",
        "transmissionStatus": "value",
        "statsLastRefreshed": "value",
        "validationStatus": "value",
        "aggregateSnapshot": {…},
        "nodeSnapshots": [{…}]
    },
    "inputPortCount": 0,
    "outputPortCount": 0,
    "operatePermissions": {…}
}
```

Reference :-https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html